# Is there a source(book, thesis, paper) that explains Lattice basis reduction algorithms (LLL, HKZ) and provides an in depth analysis of the same?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, reference-request, lattice-crypto

I want to give a slight background about me: I've Bachelors in Computer Engineering and I've been interested in Cryptography since my college days and have been following the field ever since. I'm also actively following the state-of-the-art, particularly in the area of Lattice-based-cryptography. I'm independently researching in this field and have been particularly interested in Lattice basis reduction algorithms and their involvement in cryptanalysis.
I've been trying to get a feel of Lattice basis reduction algorithms since somedays and would like to share the timeline that I followed up until this point.

1. Motivation for why lattices are important from a cryptographers standpoint.
2. Introduction to Lattices, sub-lattices and related terminology.
3. Hard Problems in Lattice based Cryptography
4. Lattice basis Reduction Algorithms

- Q1. I'm stuck at HKZ and haven't been able to get a feel of these concepts in particular. I haven't found some resources that could possibly help me in understanding it a bit better.
- Q2. I have usually found problems in 2 dimensions. Is there a resource where someone has worked out on problems for a few more dimensions (maybe, 3,4,5 and 6)?

The resources that I've been taking help from are:

1. [LLL Algorithm](https://www.ionica.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/the-LLL-Algorithms.pdf)
2. Chapter 10 and 13 of Algorithmic Cryptanalysis by Antoine Joux
3. Regev's Lecture Notes
4. Also from Nigel Smart's Crypto Made Simple for the basics of Lattice based Cryptography.
5. [A Complete Analysis of the BKZ Lattice Reduction Algorithm](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1237.pdf)