# True Lovàsz condition and definition of a LLL-reduced basis

Tags: lattice-crypto

I am studying the Shortest Vector Problem and I have some troubles understanding the actual Lovàsz condition used in the LLL algorithm.

On the one hand, the original LLL article, the [Springer book "The LLL Algorithm"](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/90061/is-there-a-sourcebook-thesis-paper-that-explains-lattice-basis-reduction-alg) and [A Complete Analysis of the BKZ Lattice Reduction Algorithm](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1237.pdf) state that the LLL algorithm outputs a reduced basis meaning that:

- $|\mu_{i,j}| \le 0.5\quad\forall 1\le j < i \le n$ and
- $\delta\|b_k^*\|^2 \le \|b^*_{k+1} + \mu_{k+1,k}b^*_k\|^2$

On the other hand, other sources, like [International
Symposium
on Mathematics,
Quantum Theory,
and Cryptography, page 198](https://library.oapen.org/handle/20.500.12657/46834), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm) and [these course notes](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Ecpeikert/lic13/lec03.pdf) state that the LLL algorithm outputs a reduced basis meaning that:

- $|\mu_{i,j}| \le 0.5\quad\forall 1\le j < i \le n$ and
- $\delta\|b_k^*\|^2 \le \|b^*_{k+1}\|^2 + \mu_{k+1,k}^2\|b^*_k\|^2$

I am a bit confused as I cannot even apply the triangle inequality to infer the latter from the former.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Little search [Prove Euclidean norm satisfies the triangle inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522665/prove-euclidean-norm-satisfies-the-triangle-inequality)

Comment: Maybe the closest answer is about the definition of a norm by Mark [On the spectral norm in lattice-based cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/106741/18298)

Comment: I thought of triangle inequality but while $\|b^*_{k+1} + \mu_{k+1,k} b^*_k\| \le \|b^*_{k+1}\| + \mu_{k+1,k}\|b^*_k\|$ is valid, if we square it we obtain $\|b^*_{k+1} + \mu_{k+1,k} b^*_k\|^2 \le \|b^*_{k+1}\|^2 + \mu_{k+1,k}^2\|b^*_k\|^2 \mathbf{+ 2\mu_{k+1,k}\|b^*_{k+1}\|\|b^*_k\|}$. I know no ways to check if $\|b^*_{k+1} + \mu_{k+1,k} b^*_k\|^2 \le \|b^*_{k+1}\|^2 + \mu_{k+1,k}^2\|b^*_k\|^2$ is also true (which is what we want). Or am I missing something?

Comment: And even if the triangle inequality explained the validity of the *second* definition, they are not equivalent: if LLL returns a basis $B$ that followed the first definition, then, assuming the inequality can be applied, it follows also the second one, but the opposite is not true (if $B$ follows the second "version" of the Lovász condition, we have no ways to say it also follows the first). PS: a small note, I'm unable to edit my former comment, but there is a typo: $\|b^*_{k+1}+\mu_{k+1,k}b^*_k\|\le\|b^*_{k+1}\|+\mathbf{|\mu_{k+1,k}|}\|b^*_k\|$

Comment: It is worth mentioning that often when working with the squared euclidean norm $\lVert x+y\rVert_2^2$, one may apply convexity of $x\mapsto \lVert x\rVert_2^2$ as a substitute for the triangle inequality. Working on this briefly I it hasn't sufficed (for me) to show equivalence, but it might plausibly be useful anyway, hence this comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Actual answer to your question:***

For the Euclidean norm, both conditions are equivalent because $b^*_{k}$ and $b^*_{k+1}$ are orthogonal.

Remember that they are obtained via Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization, thus,
$b^*_{k} \cdot b^*_{k+1} = 0$.

Also, remember that for any vectors $u$ and $v$, because the Euclidean norm is $\|u\| = \sqrt{u \cdot u}$, we have

$\|u + v\|^2 = (u + v) \cdot (u + v) 
= u\cdot u + v \cdot v + 2\cdot u\cdot v
= \|u\|^2+\|v\|^2 + 2\cdot u\cdot v$

Then, if $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal, we obtain
$\|u + v\|^2 = (u + v) \cdot (u + v) 
= u\cdot u + v \cdot v + 2\cdot u\cdot v
= \|u\|^2+\|v\|^2$.

---

***A comment about your comments:***

From your comments, it seems that you are getting confused because you are using the "squared triangular inequality", which says that

$
\|u + v\|^2 \le \|v\|^2 + \|v\|^2 + 2\|u\|\|v\|
$

This is true, of course, but this inequality is often obtained using the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality, i.e., $u\cdot v \le \|u\|\|v\|$...
That is, we write

$\|u + v\|^2 = (u + v) \cdot (u + v) 
= u\cdot u + v \cdot v + 2\cdot u\cdot v
= \|u\|^2+\|v\|^2 + 2\cdot u\cdot v ~~ (1)$

then use
Cauchy–Schwarz to obtain

$\|u + v\|^2 \le \|u\|^2+\|v\|^2 + 2\cdot \|u\|\cdot \|v\|$.

But of course, in your case, instead of using this upper bound, you can just set $u \cdot v = 0$ in Equality (1)

Comment: @kelala thanks!

Comment: So just to complete the trivial passages: $\delta\|b^*_k\|^2 \le \|b^*_{k+1} + \mu_{k+1,k}b^*_k\|^2 = \|b^*_{k+1}\|^2 + \mu_{k+1,k}^2\|b^*_k\|^2$ therefore $(\delta - \mu_{k+1,k}^2)\|b^*_k\| \le \|b^*_{k+1}\|^2$ which is the common other "version" of the Lovász condition. Thanks a lot for your answer! :)